# Function called on click is affecting all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gif

I have a page displaying a few images with a play button. When the play button is clicked, I'm trying to swap out a sibling element's src with the path to the corresponding gif. For some reason, when I click the play button on the first element, it works fine. When I click play on the second element, it swaps out the src on the second gif, BUT also restarts the first gif. If I click play on the third play button, it restarts all 3 gifs from the beginning.

HTML looks like so:

```
<div class="player">
    <div class="player--image">
        <img class="gif--control gif--play" src="/img/play-button.png" />
        <img class="player--gif" src="/assets/player-image.png" data-gif="/assets/player-gif.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div class="player--info">
        <div class="player--name">
            <h3 class="title">#23</h3>
            <h3 class="title title__large">Player Name</h3>
            <h3 class="title">Center</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="player">
    <div class="player--image">
        <img class="gif--control gif--play" src="/img/play-button.png" />
        <img class="player--gif" src="/assets/player-2-image.png" data-gif="/assets/player-2-gif.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div class="player--info">
        <div class="player--name">
            <h3 class="title">#45</h3>
            <h3 class="title title__large">Player Name</h3>
            <h3 class="title">Center</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.gif--control', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $gif = $this.siblings('.player--gif');
    var src = $gif.attr('data-gif');

    $gif.attr('src', src);
});
```

I've tried adding unique IDs to the img element that is having the src swapped, but still, all the gifs would restart when a new play button was clicked. Any help would be appreciated -- feel like I'm missing something super simple.

Comment: `$sibling` seems to be undefined in your code ?

Comment: Apologies, $sibling is actually what was used earlier, but was later changed to $gif, forgot to update the snippet I posted here. Still, when using $gif the issue persists where ALL gifs restart when one .gif--control is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an unreferenced `$sibling` call; I replaced it with `$gif` and your code seems to run fine.

```
$(document).on('click tap', '.gif--control', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $gif = $this.siblings('.player--gif');
    var src = $gif.attr('data-gif');

    $gif.attr('src', src);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7jktzLw5/

Comment: Yeah, that was an error during my copy/pasting and updating the snippet here. It's accurate in my files, but the issue still persists as mentioned above. Which is especially odd since it seems to work fine in the fiddle you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/7jktzLw5/2/

```js
$(document).on('click tap', 'img.gif--control', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $gif = $this.next('img.player--gif');
    $gif.attr('src', $gif.attr('data-gif'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player">
    <div class="player--image">
        <img class="gif--control gif--play" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/70/70776.png" />
        <img class="player--gif" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/42/42829.png" data-gif="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/44/44382.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="player--info">
        <div class="player--name">
            <h3 class="title">#23</h3>
            <h3 class="title title__large">Player Name</h3>
            <h3 class="title">Center</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="player">
    <div class="player--image">
        <img class="gif--control gif--play" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/70/70776.png" />
        <img class="player--gif" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/136/136369.png" data-gif="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/236/236540.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="player--info">
        <div class="player--name">
            <h3 class="title">#45</h3>
            <h3 class="title title__large">Player Name</h3>
            <h3 class="title">Center</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">
                Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've used `next` instead of `siblings`.

Hope this will help you.